# Script not adding new data to new column

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I've written a script to return some details from Active Directory and from Exchange and to then put those details into an array.

The problem is that the Exchange section is overwriting the existing values in the array whereas I want it to basically create a new column for the Exchange data and put it in there.

Here's the script:

```
$adusers = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonDate, createTimeStamp, mail |
           Where-Object { $_.Name -like $_."Name" } |
           Select Name, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, createTimeStamp, mail

$adusers | ForEach-Object {
    $mailboxstats = Get-Mailbox $_.mail |
                    Get-MailboxStatistics |
                    Select-Object TotalItemSize
    $adusers += $mailboxstats
}

return $adusers
```

Comment: `Where-Object { $_.Name -like $_."Name" }` You know that's always true, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for the mailbox size. Also, the condition `$_.Name -like $_."Name"` is always true, so you can simply remove your `Where-Object` filter, and the [`return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) keyword isn't required, because PowerShell functions return all non-captured output on the [Success output stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) anyway.

Change your code to something like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonDate, createTimeStamp, mail |
    Select Name, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, createTimeStamp, mail,
        @{n='MailboxSize';e={
            Get-Mailbox $_.mail |
                Get-MailboxStatistics |
                Select-Object -Expand TotalItemSize
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select-Object` to modify the items in the collection:

```
return $adusers | Select *,@{Name='TotalItemSize';Expression={
    $mailboxstats = Get-Mailbox $_.mail |
                    Get-MailboxStatistics |
                    Select-Object -Expand TotalItemSize}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for that. That did the trick perfectly.

Thank you!!!

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonDate, createTimeStamp, mail |
    Select Name, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, createTimeStamp, mail,
        @{n='MailboxSize';e={
            Get-Mailbox $_.mail |
                Get-MailboxStatistics |
                Select-Object -Expand TotalItemSize
        }}
```